# How to export a mesh's movement from Blender?

Tags: python, blender

I have a simple UV Sphere in Blender which moves from point A to point B (I've set it up by pressing "I" button on location A, clicked on LocRot then clicked on LocRot on point B as well).

I'd like to export its movement.

For exporting a camera's movement I use 
Blender Foundation\Blender\2.74\scripts\addons\io_anim_camera.py
(This is Cameras & Markers (.py) exporter.)

It's produces following output:

```
...
...
# new frame
scene.frame_set(1 + frame)
obj = cameras['Camera.003']
obj.location = -272.1265563964844, -155.54611206054688, -121.49121856689453  <-- here is the current coordinate of the camera, this is what I need for spheres
obj.scale = 0.9999998807907104, 0.9999998807907104, 0.9999999403953552
obj.rotation_euler = -1.6492990255355835, 0.00035389664117246866, 0.009288366883993149
obj.keyframe_insert('location')
obj.keyframe_insert('scale')
obj.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler')
data = obj.data
data.lens = 35.0
data.keyframe_insert('lens')
...
...
```

I'm looking for the same thing for meshes.
So here is the code of the basic exporter for cameras:

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

# <pep8 compliant>

bl_info = {
    "name": "Export Camera Animation",
    "author": "Campbell Barton",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 57, 0),
    "location": "File > Export > Cameras & Markers (.py)",
    "description": "Export Cameras & Markers (.py)",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/"
                "Scripts/Import-Export/Camera_Animation",
    "support": 'OFFICIAL',
    "category": "Import-Export",
}


import bpy


def write_cameras(context, filepath, frame_start, frame_end, only_selected=False):

    data_attrs = (
        'lens',
        'shift_x',
        'shift_y',
        'dof_distance',
        'clip_start',
        'clip_end',
        'draw_size',
        )

    obj_attrs = (
        'hide_render',
        )

    fw = open(filepath, 'w').write

    scene = bpy.context.scene

    cameras = []

    for obj in scene.objects:
        if only_selected and not obj.select:
            continue
        if obj.type != 'CAMERA':
            continue

        cameras.append((obj, obj.data))

    frame_range = range(frame_start, frame_end + 1)

    fw("import bpy\n"
       "cameras = {}\n"
       "scene = bpy.context.scene\n"
       "frame = scene.frame_current - 1\n"
       "\n")

    for obj, obj_data in cameras:
        fw("data = bpy.data.cameras.new(%r)\n" % obj.name)
        for attr in data_attrs:
            fw("data.%s = %s\n" % (attr, repr(getattr(obj_data, attr))))

        fw("obj = bpy.data.objects.new(%r, data)\n" % obj.name)

        for attr in obj_attrs:
            fw("obj.%s = %s\n" % (attr, repr(getattr(obj, attr))))

        fw("scene.objects.link(obj)\n")
        fw("cameras[%r] = obj\n" % obj.name)
        fw("\n")

    for f in frame_range:
        scene.frame_set(f)
        fw("# new frame\n")
        fw("scene.frame_set(%d + frame)\n" % f)

        for obj, obj_data in cameras:
            fw("obj = cameras['%s']\n" % obj.name)

            matrix = obj.matrix_world.copy()
            fw("obj.location = %r, %r, %r\n" % matrix.to_translation()[:])
            fw("obj.scale = %r, %r, %r\n" % matrix.to_scale()[:])
            fw("obj.rotation_euler = %r, %r, %r\n" % matrix.to_euler()[:])

            fw("obj.keyframe_insert('location')\n")
            fw("obj.keyframe_insert('scale')\n")
            fw("obj.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler')\n")

            # only key the angle
            fw("data = obj.data\n")
            fw("data.lens = %s\n" % obj_data.lens)
            fw("data.keyframe_insert('lens')\n")

            fw("\n")

    # now markers
    fw("# markers\n")
    for marker in scene.timeline_markers:
        fw("marker = scene.timeline_markers.new(%r)\n" % marker.name)
        fw("marker.frame = %d + frame\n" % marker.frame)

        # will fail if the cameras not selected
        if marker.camera:
            fw("marker.camera = cameras.get(%r)\n" % marker.camera.name)
        fw("\n")


from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper


class CameraExporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Save a python script which re-creates cameras and markers elsewhere"""
    bl_idname = "export_animation.cameras"
    bl_label = "Export Camera & Markers"

    filename_ext = ".py"
    filter_glob = StringProperty(default="*.py", options={'HIDDEN'})

    frame_start = IntProperty(name="Start Frame",
            description="Start frame for export",
            default=1, min=1, max=300000)
    frame_end = IntProperty(name="End Frame",
            description="End frame for export",
            default=250, min=1, max=300000)
    only_selected = BoolProperty(name="Only Selected",
            default=True)

    def execute(self, context):
        write_cameras(context, self.filepath, self.frame_start, self.frame_end, self.only_selected)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.frame_start = context.scene.frame_start
        self.frame_end = context.scene.frame_end

        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def menu_export(self, context):
    import os
    default_path = os.path.splitext(bpy.data.filepath)[0] + ".py"
    self.layout.operator(CameraExporter.bl_idname, text="Cameras & Markers (.py)").filepath = default_path


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(menu_export)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(menu_export)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

So is it possible? How to change this code to export the movement of a spheres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, If you want to export the movement not as a Python script but in Text or in CSV format. Then look at the following code snippet.

CSV export can work for camera like this:

```
fw("# frame camera x y z qx qy qz qw\n")

for f in frame_range:
    scene.frame_set(f)
    for obj, obj_data in cameras:
        matrix = obj.matrix_world.copy()
        fw("%d," % f)
        fw("%s," % obj.name)
        fw("%r,%r,%r," % matrix.to_translation()[:])
        fw("%r,%r,%r,%r" % matrix.to_quaternion()[:])
        fw("\n")

from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper

class CameraExporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Export camera trajectory to a file"""
    bl_idname = "export_trajectory.cameras"
    bl_label = "Export camera trajectory"

    filename_ext = ".csv"

filter_glob = StringProperty(default="*.csv", options={'HIDDEN'})
```

In my opinion it should work similarly for any other objects in scene. 
Not yet tried for other objects though!